# Hibernate Criteria API - update many rows with one database query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm fetching from database bunch of persons like this:

```
public List<Object[]> getLimitedBunchOfPersons(Integer limit) {

    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Person.class, "person")
            .setProjection(
                    Projections.projectionList()
                      .add(Projections.property("person.personId"), "personId")
                      )
            .createAlias("person.status","status")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("status.statusId", 1L))
            .addOrder(Order.asc("person.createdOn"));

    return criteria.setMaxResults(limit).list();
}
```

As I needed to speed things up, I only fetched ID's of my entity. Important thing to note is that I'm manipulating with large number of rows and for one query had to use `maxResults` limitation.

Now my problem is, how to easily update with Hibernate Criteria API in one database query all fetched rows from previously mentioned query?

Plain SQL query would go something like this:

```
UPDATE PERSON
SET STATUS = 2, CREATED_ON = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE STATUS = 1;
```

It's important to note that update method have to use same `order` and `limit` as `getLimitedBunchOfPersons()` method.

Comment: You can get the ids of persons returned in previous criteria query and you can pass these ids in where condition of update query .

Comment: You gave me a great idea

Answer (score 1):

For Single Object it will work as follows after your code

```
Person per= (Person) criteria.uniqueResult();
per.setCreatedOn("crtBy");
currentSession.merge(per);
```

Now if comes in list you can iterate list by passing mentioned code in your List iteration